# Changing the text color inside a PrimeVue Dropdown Menu

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I'm working on a Vue.js project that uses PrimeVue attributes. I needed a dropdown menu and I used PrimeVue's . It works great, but when I select an option on the dropdown, the selected option text becomes white. Dropdown itself is also white, so I cannot see the chosen option. You should know that this issue doesn't happen when I use a light PrimeVue theme. But when I use a dark PrimeVue theme, this issue appears.

PrimeVue themes I am using:
primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css
primevue/resources/themes/lara-dark-blue/theme.css

Again, the dark one has the problem. So, I want to change the color of the text inside the Dropdown. I thought that if I make the text color black as a fixed color, the issue would be handled. Or any other suggestions?

I tried to assign a background-color to black but it did not solve my problem.